# Opengl es2.0 crashes during onPause

Tags: android, opengl-es, crash, opengl-es-2.0, onpause

For some reason, Opengl es is crashing when onPause is called in my android program. (Whether via rotation or back button/home button being pressed.)
I have done a bunch of debuging, and have determined that the cause of the problem has something to do with shaders not being unloaded. However, I have tried unloading them manually and still get the crash. Here is a stripped down version of my program that can be used to recreate the bug. 
Any help solving this problem is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private int program;
private int vertexShader;
private int fragmentShader;
private int texture;
private GLSurfaceView glView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    glView= new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    glView.setRenderer(this);
    setContentView(glView);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    glView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    String VertexShaderSource=...//See vertex shader code

    String FragmentShaderSource=...//See fragment shader code

    //Compile vertex shader.
    vertexShader= GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader,VertexShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    String vCompileLog=GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);

    //Compile fragment shader.
    fragmentShader=GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader,FragmentShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    String fCompileLog=GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);

    //Link shaders
    program=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program,vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program,fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program,1,"textureCoordinate");
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
    String programLinkLog=GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    //Enable textures, and load a texture to memory.
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Bitmap bmptexture= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.texture);  //Load the bitma
    IntBuffer textureID=IntBuffer.allocate(1);                                          //Create a textureID buffer.
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1,textureID);                                                  //Generate an Id for the texture.
    texture=textureID.get(0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID.get(0));
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmptexture, 0);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) { 
    //..Note that setting up the glviewport here doesn't solve the problem.
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //see onDraw code
}
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
FragmentShaderSource="" +
            "uniform sampler2D textureUnit;"+
            "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;"+
            "void main()"+
            "{"+
            "vec4 color=texture2D(textureUnit,textureCoordinateVarying);"+
            "gl_FragColor=color;"+
            "}";
```

Vertex shader:

```
VertexShaderSource=""+
            "uniform vec3 translate;"+
            "attribute vec4 position;"+
            "attribute vec2 textureCoordinate;"+
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;"+
            "void main()"+
            "{"+
            "     gl_Position= position + vec4(translate.x,translate.y,translate.z,0.0);"+
            "     textureCoordinateVarying=textureCoordinate;"+
            "}";
```

onDraw code:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float destPoints[]={
            0,0,0,1.0f,
            0,1,0,1.0f,
            1,0,0,1.0f,
            1,0,0,1.0f,
            0,1,0,1.0f,
            1,1,0,1.0f,
    };
    float srcPoints[]={
            0,0,
            0,1,
            1,0,
            1,0,
            0,1,
            1,1,
    };
    ByteBuffer BBDestBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(destPoints.length*4);
    ByteBuffer BBSrcBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(srcPoints.length*4);
    FloatBuffer vDestBuffer;
    FloatBuffer vSrcBuffer;

    BBDestBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    BBSrcBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vDestBuffer=BBDestBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vSrcBuffer=BBSrcBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

    int TranslateDrawingLocation=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program,"translate");
    GLES20.glUniform3f(TranslateDrawingLocation, 0, 0, 0);

    int TranslateTextureLocation=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program,"textureUnit");
    GLES20.glUniform1i(TranslateTextureLocation,0);

    vDestBuffer.put(destPoints);
    vDestBuffer.position(0);
    vSrcBuffer.put(srcPoints);
    vSrcBuffer.position(0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 4, vDestBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, vSrcBuffer);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,0,6 );
```

**Below is the logcat log (Without the GLES memory dump):**

11-26 02:54:03.373      280-417/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{40e7a8a0 u0 com.tests.simpleegl2/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state

11-26 02:54:03.401      280-909/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4138cb70 u0 com.tests.simpleegl2/com.tests.simpleegl2.MainActivity}

11-26 02:54:03.401      280-909/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Force-removing child win Window{40f67860 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{4138cb70 u0 com.tests.simpleegl2/com.tests.simpleegl2.MainActivity}

11-26 02:54:03.421      280-312/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=204, events=0x9

11-26 02:54:03.441      280-481/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failed looking up window
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@40ebb0e8 does not exist
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8102)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8093)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:932)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:433)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

11-26 02:54:03.441      280-481/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: null

Edit: Oddly enough, changing **varying vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;** to **varying highp vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;**  in the vertex shader seems to have solved this problem. **Well at least for my phone, the emulator still crashes. Giving up on the emulator as it is worthless.

Comment: I believe you lose EGL context when the app goes into pause and thus kills the window. Try to reinitiate the EGL context when you return from the pause.

Comment: Isn't that what this is doing in onCreate?
    
    glView= new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    glView.setRenderer(this);
    setContentView(glView);


Besides, it's crashing during onPause not onResume. 
The weird thing is if I give it a pass through Shader, it doesn't crash. The only problem with that is a pass through Shader is worthless for sprite batching/texturing.

Additionally, I tried loading the texture after the glsurfaceview had it's renderer set, but for some reason it didn't load properly.